# ScrollView on an iOS app in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uiscrollview

I have a ViewController and my View is too large, so I'm trying to implement a simple ScrollView but I don't know how to do. I Tried to do `Embed in >> ScrollView` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Scrollview in the xib or storyboard file of your VC. Create the view seperately and add it as a subview inside the scrollview. Or you could simply drag it inside the scrollview.  Set content size of scrollview to be equal to that view's size. If you still need help, use this tutorial. http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift

Comment: I'm on raywenderlich tutorial, I tryied to follow your response I have: à View in a ScrollView, when I run my app, it scroll in width but not in height, and I only want to scroll in height

Comment: Did you set the content size correctly? Your view is either 320px or 375 px right? whatever it is, it should not scroll horizontally. as maximum width for fortent size is equal to screensize

Comment: What is the width size for the content ?

Comment: set it to self.view.frame.size.width

Comment: Oh I have to write swift codes ? I can't do it on the inspectors attributes ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need wide screen so here is example how you can make three times wider that usual one.

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let view1: View1 = View1(nibName: "View1", bundle: nil)

    addChildViewController(view1)
    scrollView.addSubview(view1.view)
    view1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    let view2: View2 = View2(nibName: "View2", bundle: nil)

    addChildViewController(view2)
    scrollView.addSubview(view2.view)
    view2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    var view2Frame: CGRect = view2.view.frame
    view2Frame.origin.x = view.frame.width
    view2.view.frame = view2Frame


    let view3: View3 = View3(nibName: "View3", bundle: nil)

    addChildViewController(view3)
    scrollView.addSubview(view3.view)
    view3.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    var view3Frame: CGRect = view3.view.frame
    view3Frame.origin.x = view.frame.width * 2
    view3.view.frame = view3Frame

    self.scrollView.contentSize.width = view.frame.width * 3
  }
```

So basically you create scrollView and add here three views and each view has it's new origin point. You can enable or disable paging in storyboard. And that is it!

Comment: I want to do it with only ne view if it's possible